# Access Denied error in XMLHTTPRequest.Send

Tags: delphi

I am using following Delphi code to download attachment content for a JIRA issue. The Send request is raising exception for Access Denied. Is the any security certificate related issue:

```
class function TnsXmlHttpReq.GetRequestForStream(const p_Url, p_UsrName,
  p_Password: String; out p_Status: Integer): TMemoryStream;
var
  LBody : OleVariant;
  Stream: IStream;
  OleStream: TOleStream;
begin
  Result:= nil;
  p_Status:= 0;

  if FHttpRequest = nil then
    FHttpRequest:= CoXMLHTTPRequest.Create;

  FHttpRequest.open('GET', p_Url, false, p_UsrName, p_Password);
  FHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('X-Atlassian-Token', 'no-check');
  FHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic '+EncodeBase64(p_UsrName+':'+p_Password));
  FHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');


  //send request
  FHttpRequest.send('');

  p_Status:= FHttpRequest.status;

  if FHttpRequest.status <> 200 then
    Exit;

  Result:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream := IUnknown(FHttpRequest.ResponseStream) as IStream;
  OleStream := TOleStream.Create(Stream);
  try
    OleStream.Position := 0;
    Result.CopyFrom(OleStream, OleStream.Size);
  finally
    OleStream.Free;
  end;//try..finally...
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use standard Delphi HttpClient as following

```
uses System.Net.HttpClient;

function GetAttachment(const AURL: string; const AUserName: string;
  const APassword: string): TStream;
var
  HttpClient: THttpClient;
  BasicAuth: string;
begin
  HttpClient := THttpClient.Create;
  try
    Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
    BasicAuth := TRESTHTTPProcs.CreateBasicAuthenticationString('', AUserName, APassword);
    HttpClient.Get(AURL, Result, TNetHeaders.Create(
      TNameValuePair.Create('X-Atlassian-Token', 'nocheck'),
      TNameValuePair.Create(HTTP_HEADERFIELD_AUTH, BasicAuth)
      ));
  finally
    HttpClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```